# decimal to binary conversion using recursive functions

Tags: c

I have an assignment to convert a number from decimal to binary. My problem is that I need to have it printed out directly from the function, instead of returning it back to main. Due to this, my printed out code is in the wrong order. (ex: for 6, my code prints out `011` instead of `110`)

This is what I have been using for the function:

```
int printBinary(int integer) {
    int remainder;

    if (integer < 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        remainder = integer % 2;
        printf("%d", remainder);
        integer = integer / 2;
        printBinary(integer);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a suggestion on how I can print it out in reverse, or a different approach entirely?

Answer (score 2):

You should just print the digit **after** the recursive call that prints the higher order bits.

Note also that your function prints nothing for `0`, which is probably incorrect.

Here is a simplified version:

```
int printBinary(int integer) {
    if (integer > 1)
        printBinary(integer / 2);
    printf("%d", integer % 2);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function prints binary digits starting from the tail. Just change the order of recursive call and printf.

```
int printBinary(int integer)  {

    int remainder;
    if (integer < 1)  {
    return 0;
    }
    else  {
        printBinary(integer / 2);
        remainder = integer % 2;
        printf("%d", remainder);
    return 0;
    }
}
```

It was

```
printBinary(6);
printf("%d", 0);
printBinary(3);
printf("%d", 1);
printBinary(1);
printf("%d", 1);
printBinary(0);
```

It is now

```
printBinary(6);
printBinary(3);
printBinary(1);
printBinary(0);
printf("%d", 1);
printf("%d", 1);
printf("%d", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you could try something like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void printBinary(int num) {
  int i;

  // findind the first non 0 binary position from MSB
  for (i = sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT - 1; i >= 0 && (num & (1 << i)) == 0; i--);

  for (; i >= 0; i--) // start the printing from here, so trailing 0's avoided
    if ((num & (1 << i)) == 0)
      printf("0");
    else
      printf("1");
}

int main() 
{
    printBinary(6);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i think that the answer is helpful, but the question is about to find conversion using recursive function !

Comment: "or a different approach entirely" From this I assumed he may interested in other approach also just to see one at least.

Comment: Sorry, your implementation is wrong. I think, it only works correctly from 2 to 15.
The first loop seems to be the reason. You are dealing with `sizeof(int)` which is not the number of bits. I would assume a factor CHAR_BITS from limits.h.

`for (i = sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT - 1; i > 0 && (num & (1 << i)) == 0; i--);` is better.
And `if (i != 0)` is superfluos.

Comment: @MiCo Ohh, you are right. Good catch. Fixed it, thanks.